# How to have GIF image with action in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I like to have **GIF** image in Power BI report along with **action** for that image. Whenever I tried to import GIF image from the local system it becomes a static image.

**For Eg.,** I have a couple of report page for analysis dashboard. I need to have **Next gif image** in Page1 with action to navigate Page2 and **Previous gif image** in Page2 with action to navigate Page1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to your table/query with gif URLs. 
Change "Data category" of that column to "Image URL" and you are good to go.

Sample data you can try

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows( 
               Json.Document(
                 Binary.Decompress(
                   Binary.FromText("i45WyigpKSi20tfP1EvPTEst0kvOz9V3zIlIA3GVYmMB",
                                    BinaryEncoding.Base64), 
                   Compression.Deflate)),
                   let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) 
                             in type table [#"Web link" = _t])
in
    Source
```

Here is the result:

[image]

---

> Actually, I need to have next/previous gif image in my report.

In this case, you either need to find a visual that both can "play" gifs and supports action, or you can place a button over an image visual (image by cloudscope visual in this case. You can import it from the marketplace) and use it's "Action" property to navigate between pages. 
*Note*: button should be placed above the image visual in the selection pane

[image]

Here is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I include an action button for this gif image? Actually, I need to have next/previous gif image in my report.

Comment: @WannaCoffee It's not clear to me at this point what you are trying to achieve. Can you edit your question and explain in full what exactly you are after? If you need to switch between next/prev images a filter on a table with Images would be a better choice than an action. Unless you want to jump back and forth between your report pages.

Comment: Nick Krasnov: I have updated question, please check